# run time styles in angular material design

Tags: angular-material

When I changed the css style in the internal css component using angular2 material design, all components changed to the same style.

Ex:

When I used this line in internal css component, all components implemented the same style.

```
::ng-deep .ng-star-inserted > td:nth-child(1) { color:#3f51b5 }
```

How I can fix this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you mean with 'internal css component'? You mean the css file of a particular component or the `styles.css` file that applies to all components? If you want the css rule to apply to only one component then you should put it in the css file that comes with that component, not in styles.css. To prevent your problem from happening please do the following:

In the css file of the particular component add !important after the color css style rule and remove `::ng-deep`.

```
.ng-star-inserted > td:nth-child(1) { color:#3f51b5 !important}
```

Comment: I mean the css file of a particular component , Yes I understand that

Comment: try this: `.ng-star-inserted > td:nth-child(1) { color:#3f51b5  !important}`

Comment: also please not that `::ng-deep` is deprecated so you shouldn't use it. More info about that here https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: if you want to use ::ng-deep you should make sure the `encapsulation:` field in the component decorator has been set to `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`, or atleast not to anything else (because this setting also happens to be the default)

Comment: i gave you 2 suggestions, the one about !important and the one about encapsulation. Could you tell me which one worked for you so that i can include the solution in my answer post? Also please accept my post as the answer after i've made the edit.

Comment: I tried the first solution only
.ng-star-inserted > td:nth-child(1) { color:#3f51b5 !important}
without ::ng-deep
sure

Comment: You didn't mark it as the answer, please press the V sign. Thank you